# php новостная лента

Tags: php

Мне нужно сделать ленту новостей есть примерно вот такая конструкция но она не моя

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "103",
            "title": "sdvdgddgasdfgd",
            "body": "dfgsdflgdsfgdsf",
            "created": 1501483394,
            "author": {
                "name": "Caria Estates",
                "logo": "http:\/\images\/logos\/cariaestates.png"
            },
            "image1": "http:\/\/img\/social\/luxury_apartments_with_sea_view_for_sale_in_alanya_2.jpg",
            "image2": "http:\/\/img\/social\/luxury_beach_front_property_for_sale_in_alanya_11.jpg",
            "likes": 19
        }]}
```

ее у меня получается вывести на моей странице и все хорошо, вопрос в том как создать такую конструкцию что лучше при этом использовать и где лучше всего хранить всю информацию например в database(MySQL) или просто создать ARRAY через JSON и хранить все это там

Answer (score 0):

Я предпочитаю использовать database(MySQL).

Заводим таблицу news(id, title, body, created, author_id, likes) в ней храним новости.

Данные об авторах храним в таблице author(id, name, logo)

Данные о картинках новости храним в таблице news_image(id, news_id, save_path)

И при выводе запрашиваем данные из таблицы news и из связанных записей в таблицах author и news_image

Формируем массив из данных и json_encode от него выводим.

Comment: а зачем формировать в JSON если можно и так вывести извиняюсь за глупый вопрос просто не могу понять смысла и еще один вопрос с частью body какое устанавливать ей значение в базе данных типо varchar(10000000000)????

Comment: body - text, он до 64 кб, можно mediumtext если его не хватает. Если у тебя новости всегда будут одни и те же, то сделай готовый JSON. Если новости добавляются, и надо сделать админку, с добавлением картинок, их обработкой, проверкой прав доступа и т.д. - тот тут PHP+MySQL

Comment: то есть если у меня новости работают по одному принципу лого, имя, время создания поста, картинка одна или две, то лучше сделать шаблон из JSON и хранить все там? либо можно просто использовать Sql? или это неправильно и медленно может быть? В плане загрузки

Comment: JSON - это ручной ввод и потенциальные ошибки ввода, которые могут привести к тому, что страница новостей не будет отображаться. Но это быстро, если новостей немного. Так что дело скорее в удобстве, в том сколько у тебя времени на разработку и сколько навыков.

Answer (score 0):

Для этих целей используют и базу данных, и JSON файлы, и просто сгенерированные html страницы кеша. Последний используют в связке с базой данных. Нет смысла подтягивать контент, каждый раз при обращении к странице, если он не интерактивный, а статичный. Используют шаблонизатор, который будет кешировать вывод, тем самым снизит нагрузку на базу данных и на сам сайт в целом.

Comment: а можно пожалуйста как нибудь поподробней и желательно с кодом каким нибудь или с ссылками

Comment: достаточно в поиске поискать статьи на тему php шаблонизатор. Но опять же, все зависит от нагрузки на сайт. Если там будет несколько просмотров в день, то можно смело выводить все из базы данных, как есть. Но если нагрузка достаточно высокая, плюс есть модули комментариев, которые тоже будут нагружать эту же базу данных, нужно думать о кешировании вывода.

Comment: ну пока ожидается нагрузка 100-200 человек в день

Comment: можете не переживать, оставьте все как есть, незачем просто так усложнять проект. Однако, можете почитать о видах кеширования https://habrahabr.ru/company/zerotech/blog/316316/